# .Net MailAddress fails on "ñ" in email address

Tags: c#, localization

The following code throws an exception of "An invalid character was found in the mail header: 'ñ'.":

```
string email = "ñ@c.com";
MailAddress to = new MailAddress(email);
```

The  actual address I'm running into this is a valid address, but the MailAddress class throws an error whenever I try and use it.

Comment: Hmm... can't reproduce on [Ideone](http://ideone.com/TMd9s). No exception being thrown there

Comment: @Cameron: It'll compile, it won't run (it throws a runtime exception).

Comment: @Noon: According to Ideone it is also running successfully

Comment: @Cameron: Then "Ideone" is wrong.

Comment: @Noon: Well, it *is* running under Mono 2.8 -- perhaps the implementation is different

Comment: @Cameron: Makes sense if you think of where the creator of Mono is from.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yeah, interesting. According to Wikipedia: [Email Address](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_address), it's strictly defined as being a subset of ASCII, so that is technically invalid.

So, it seems you just strictly can't send email to that address from .NET (using the System.Net.Mail classes, anyway).

Comment: Yes. [RFC 5322 sections 3.2.3 and 3.2.4](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5322#section-3.2.3) standardize the allowable characters in atoms and quoted strings respectively, and the legal character sets for both are specified as subsets of US-ASCII.

Comment: It looks like in the near future it'll extend to Unicode, but for now, seems to be just ASCII.  Thanks!

Comment: Just to note (in case anyone else stumbles across this), as of .NET 4.0, it appears that ñ is allowed in the address.